# c# async method and return await

Tags: c#, asynchronous, return, async-await

one simple question. I found some methods with this "logic" and "architecture".

```
public async Task<T> FindAsync(params object[] keys)
{
    return await this.context.FindAsync(keys);
}
```

One single instruction with its await. Since the method is async you have to do this (otherwise compiler errors occur).
IMHO i can't find why you should use this pattern because if the method is async you probably want to perform different tasks in parallel. If you sync the execution with the await keyword you make the method close to sync and you loose all the performance gain of the managed thread pool mechanism of .net.
What is your opinion? I'm in wrong?

Comment: You are not required to use await; you have to remove both async and await keywords, in that case. Probably the only benefit afforded here is that this FindAsync method will appear in call stacks if there is an exception.

Comment: `await` doesn't make code synchronous. `async`/`await` don't have anything to do with the thread pool. You may find my [`async` intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) helpful.

Answer (score 5):

If you're calling this method like this:

```
await FindAsync(); // this method waits for the task to complete
```

Then it doesn't make any sense to return await inside this method, you can just change it to:

```
public Task<T> FindAsync(params object[] keys)
{
    return this.context.FindAsync(keys); // Start and return the task
}
```

Then the caller awaits the task to Complete.

Comment: I agree with you. The caller of async methods should await all async methods in order to optimize and run some parts of code (async methods) in parallel.